# Accessing JAR resources

Tags: java, jar, resources, embedded-resource, relative-path

I have a `jar` file with resources (mainly configuration for caches, logging, etc) that I want to distribute.

I'm having a problem with the relative paths for those resources, so I did what I've found in another stackoverflow question, which said that this was a valid way:

```
ClassInTheSamePackageOfTheResource.class.getResourceAsStream('resource.xml');
```

Sadly this does not work.

Any ideas? Thanks!

> PS: Obviously I cannot use absolute
>   paths, and I'd like to avoid
>   environment variables if possible

Comment: Is the resource file in the same folder as the class file? Is this a standalone application or running in a web server?

Comment: It's in the same folder indeed. It's a jar meant to be included in a web application, yes (but I think that should be irrelevant)

Comment: it is relevant the rules for searching resources associated with a given class are implemented by the defining class loader. So your web app's classloader might behave slightly differently based on implementation. Just a thought.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure that your resource folder is listed as a source folder in your project settings. Also, make sure that the resource folder is set to export when you build your jar.

You can add a .zip extension to your jar file then open it up to ensure that your resources are included and at the expected location.

I always use absolute paths like this:

```
InputStream input = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/image.gif");
```

When you use absolute paths, "/" is the root folder in the jar file, not the root folder of the host machine.

Comment: Indeed, I used the (jar) absolute path method you described and it worked! Don't know why it didn't do the trick with the relative one... but good enough is good enough

Answer (score 1):

I always have to puzzle through [`getResourceAsStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to make this work. If "resource.xml" is in `org/pablo/opus`, I *think* you want this:

```
Name.class.getResourceAsStream("org.pablo.opus.resource.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

where the resource.xml found? If in the root of the source tree, try to prefix it with /.

Comment: It's not on the root of the source tree. It's inside a package

Comment: so treat the fully qualified name as an absolute path, for example com.me.and.u.effects.css would be accessed as /com/me/and/u/effects.css

Answer (score 1):

I usually store files and other resources and then retrieve them as URLs:

```
URL url = MyClass.class.getResource("/design/someResource.png");
```

Within a static context, or otherwise:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/design/someResource.png");
```

From an instance.

The above snippets assume that design is a top level folder within the jar.  In general, if the path begins with a "/" it assumes an absolute path, otherwise it's relative from the class location.