# Accessing resources within JAR

Tags: java, jar, embedded-resource

I'm creating a Java application that uses a Maven profile and a JAR build.

I have some XML files in this folder : project/src/main/resources/XML/*.xml

The src/main/resources folder is a source folder in my build path so I have my project.jar/XML/*.xml built in the JAR binary.

I'd like to be able to find and list those files "/XML/*.xml" in JAR execution. Is my structure good for this ?

I have no problem running with the Maven profile, I just can't find the good way to find and list those files.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639943/accessing-jar-resources

Comment: I've seen that question before, but they don't use a "XML/*.xml" pattern. I think this is the main problem here.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a *good* way.  If you don't mind the dependency on `spring-core` then they have a nice [`PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html) that abstracts away from the differences between JARs and directories.

```
PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver =
   new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(MyClass.class.getClassLoader());
Resource[] xmls = resolver.getResources("classpath*:XML/*.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list the contents of your jar file, you could just simply run:

```
jar tf ./path/to/your/file.jar
```

or

```
jar tf ./path/to/your/file.jar | grep XML
```

Now from code (I believe this is not the only way to do it) and you have to replace `Main` with whatever class you are in that is within the jar:

```
              List<String> myJarXmlFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
                       // replace Main here   
        CodeSource src = Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
        if (src != null) {
            URL jar = src.getLocation();
            ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(jar.openStream());
            ZipEntry entry = null;
            while ((entry = zip.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                if (entry.getName().contains("XML/")
                        && entry.getName().endsWith(".xml")) {
                    myJarXmlFiles.add(entry.getName());
                }
            }
        } else {
            // failed
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: That will work when running from JAR but not when running debug.

Comment: Which is exactly what the OP requested :/

Comment: That's embarrassing as I would like those files to be accessed when I'm launching the app from Eclipse. Is it a no way ?

Answer (score 0):

This code demonstrates how to find out the path of a jar on your app's classpath and list the contents of a folder.

```
// you need to get of a URL of any class in your jar
URL url = Appender.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
           .getLocation();
File file = new File(url.getFile());
System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
JarFile jar = new JarFile(file);
Enumeration<JarEntry> i = jar.entries();
while (i.hasMoreElements()) {
    JarEntry e = i.nextElement();
    if (e.getName().startsWith("META-INF/")) {
        System.out.println(e.getName());
    }
}
jar.close();
```

output

```
jar:file:/C:/temp/.repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar!/org/apache/log4j/Appender.class
C:\temp\.repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/
META-INF/LICENSE
META-INF/NOTICE
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/log4j/
META-INF/maven/log4j/log4j/
META-INF/maven/log4j/log4j/pom.properties
META-INF/maven/log4j/log4j/pom.xml
```