# Include external file (not jar) to executable jar

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

If I load some (say *.txt) file to my java app, how can I inlcude it to my final executable jar to make it portable (means if I move my jar to another machine it's not required to move this *.txt file with it)?

Note that I don't need the content of file I need the **file itself**. And how should I write the path to this file from the code?

```
String path = "path/to/file/"; //Yeah it should be String
```

I'm using IntellijIDEA and I can include any files to my final jar but can't figure out where to place it. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding resources in intellij for java project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717038/adding-resources-in-intellij-for-java-project)

Comment: @Joe Thanks, looks usefull, but so much letters :D, I'll check it out

Comment: @Joe But as you see that question hasn't accepted answer and the author marked that it doesn't solve his question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing JAR resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639943/accessing-jar-resources)

Answer (score 3):

Just put your file into project's **src** folder - for example *src/resource/file.txt*. When you build your project, whole *src* content will be put in resulting jar. You can access your file with the following code:

```
this.getClass().getResource("/resource/file.txt");
```

An example of reading all lines:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/resource/file.txt");
Path path = Paths.get(url.toURI());
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Thanks for input. But my function waits for a `string` format file path as a parameter. Using `toString()` I get the string like `file:/full/path/to/file/` so it's not usable for me.

Comment: Thank you very much! you save my day

Answer (score 0):

You need something like the below

```
<target name="somejar" depends="compile">
      <jar jarfile="${somejar.jar}">
        <fileset dir="${bin.dir}">
          <include name="**/*.class"/>
        </fileset>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${basedir}">
          <include name="config/*.properties"/>
          <include name="config/*.txt"/>
        </fileset>
      </jar>
    </target>
```

this will put all the needed class and property files together. You can code the location of file from the base of the project till you reach the file.