# What is the best way to create and read a runnable jar?

Tags: java

is this the correct way to read a jar file:

```
rules="./src/main/resources/Rules.json"
```

If not, what's the best way to do this?

Comment: are you asking, that should reading file from resources in a runnable jar a good practice?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639943/accessing-jar-resources

Comment: You should read this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please have a look at [ask] and provide [mcve]. Then we will know what you expect us to help you with.

Answer (score 0):

```
App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Rules.json");
```

is a better way to go with resource files.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative to ma3stro's answer using Guava:

```
String rules =
    Resources.toString(Resources.getResource("Rules.json");, Charsets.UTF_8)
```

Comment: @xenteros: it's really not clear what you are asking. This is to read a resource from a JAR file, whether it's runnable/executable or not. If you want to create a JAR, that's a different question. And if you want to extract a file from a JAR that's also a different question.

Comment: Read the title of the question which you have just answered. `What is the best way to create and read a runnable jar?`

Comment: @xenteros: ok, read the body of the question: the code snippet OP shows has nothing to do with creating a jar, or reading a resource where the JAR being runnable has any impact. I'm happy to help, if we get clear details.

Comment: Why do you answer such a question then? Vote to close instead. This topic is a rubbish.

Comment: @xenteros: because the normal assumption is that people don't necessarily write English well, or know how to ask good questions at first. Closing first-time users' questions is a surefire way to make them go away. And from the question, it seems clear that OP is confusing several concepts so I go for the one most likely to answer what he wants. Also, I did vote to close. Maybe step away from your keyboard if the internet pisses you off.

Comment: [so] community is strong enough to execute [ask] and [answer] rules. If we begin accepting questions like this one [so] will get flooded with low quality questions.

Comment: @xenteros: it is already flooded, and it deals naturally with it by doing what we did to close them until reworded. Search engines do the rest. Attempting to improve or answer them in the meantime does not hurt anyone (except my own use of time, in that case).