# How to give relative path for a file?

Tags: java, relative-path

When i give the absolute path of twitter.R file it runs correctly. like this:

```
c.eval("source(\"C:\\\\Users\\\\Ruttab\\\\workspace\\\\RserveConnect\\\\src\\\\main\\\\resources\\\\Script\\\\twitter.R\")");
```

When i give the relative path it doesnt run and gives me an error. like this:

```
c.eval("source(\"/src/main/resources/Resources/Rscripts/twitter.R\")");
```

How to give relative path for the file twitter.R

This is my project hieachy:

[image]

Comment: relative to what ? How does the process know where to start resolving the relative path ? You know that your file is packaged in a Jar ? You should rather declare it as a `Resource`

Comment: @JeremyGrand how do i declare it as a Resource?

Comment: refer to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639943/accessing-jar-resources

Answer (score 3):

```
String relative = new File(base).toURI().relativize(new 
File(path).toURI()).getPath();
```

add an example:

```
String path = "/var/caiyongji/tmp/abc.txt";
String base = "/var/caiyongji";
String relative = new File(base).toURI().relativize(new File(path).toURI()).getPath();
// relative == "tmp/abc.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path pathAbsolute = Paths.get("/var/data/stuff/xyz.dat");
        Path pathBase = Paths.get("/var/data");
        Path pathRelative = pathBase.relativize(pathAbsolute);
        System.out.println(pathRelative);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi jdpom, please [edit] to correct the formatting of your first two lines (needs indented 4 spaces). It is also helpful if you include some comments or a description of what the code does. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `Path` with relative paths, but that won't solve your issue. You cannot expect your java process to know the root directory of your source files just like that.

Your project is likely to be built and packaged as a jar (or a war) and the relative path to your resources may change.

The proper solution to your issue is to get it from the classpath, as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2640117/7573818)

Short version :`InputStream input = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Resources/Rscripts/twitter.R");`

Comment: This is the outpuit i am getting when printed input = java.io.BufferedInputStream@210366b4. Isn't this wrong?

Comment: You need to decode the content of the `InputStream`. you can wrap the stream with an `InputStreamReader`.

Comment: this doesnt work. The content of my r script is run. It doesnt give me the relative path

Comment: I never said it would give you the relative path. I was pointing out the way to access files in your src/main/resources folder. Because, in a general manner, files used at runtime aren't the same as files found at compile time.

Comment: Okay. I assumed your answer would get me the relative path